# Extract attributes values with SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf

I want to use SPARQL to get subjects `rdf:value` which have the following resource : http://purl.org/dc/terms/LCSH

```
<dcterms:subject>
    <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N4192a7fb1dd6438c94649f7afd192f09">
        <rdf:value>United States. Declaration of Independence</rdf:value>
        <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/LCSH"/>
    </rdf:Description>
</dcterms:subject>
<dcterms:subject>
    <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N887b24b564624253b374ee7c95f0ed51">
       <rdf:value>United States -- History -- Revolution, 1775-1783 -- Sources</rdf:value>
       <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/LCSH"/>
    </rdf:Description>
</dcterms:subject>
<dcterms:subject>
    <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N1b3ed5adb91b4b0c8aa1215180fdfa96">
       <rdf:value>JK</rdf:value>
       <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/LCC"/>
    </rdf:Description>
</dcterms:subject>
<dcterms:subject>
   <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="Nc5deb6e74cc6462fbeeb8c1871983f09">
      <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/LCC"/>
      <rdf:value>KF</rdf:value>
   </rdf:Description>
</dcterms:subject>
```

Is there a way to extract the `rdf:resource` and use it to filter the subjects?

Comment: This isn't a complete rdf/xml snippet.  There is something (not shown) that *has* a bunch of subjects,  each one described by a rdf:Description element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rdf/xml snippet isn't complete,  so we can't write a perfect query, but you'll want something like this:

```sql
select ?value {
  ?x dcterms:subject ?subject .
  ?subject rdf:value ?value .
  ?subject dcam:memberOf  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/LCSH> .
}
```

If you want to make that a bit shorter, you could do:

```sql
select ?value {
  ?x dcterms:subject [
      rdf:value ?value ;
      dcam:memberOf  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/LCSH> ]
}
```

And if you really only care about things that have rdf:value properties and are members of LCSH you could skip the first triple altogether:

```sql
select ?value {
  ?x rdf:value ?value ;
      dcam:memberOf  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/LCSH> 
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked ! I have another question how would I do if only want to show for instance the content of all the rdf:nodeID contained by rdf:description ?

Comment: In other word is it possible to display directly attributes using sparql ?

Comment: @theasc721 I don't see rdf:nodeId in your snippet,  but as I recall,  nodeId is an artifact of the rdf/xml serialization, not part of the actual rdf data. I'd suggest excitement with Brisas queries like `select * {?s ?p ?o}` to look at the actual triples in the data, not the rdf/xml serialization. Or convert the rdf/xml to turtle or n-triples.